# showing NSMutabelArray in tableViewController in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am passing NSMutableArray to another a tableview and I want to show it in the table view. My NSMutableArray is as follows

```
2017-02-07 18:32:24.086 krib[13753:2978659] (
    "Balcony.png",
    "Utilities Included.png",
    "Air-conditioning.png",
    "Stove.png",
    "WiFi Included.png",
    "Queen Bed.png",
    "Dining Table.png",
    "Washing Machine.png",
    "Dryer.png",
    "Sofa.png",
    "TV.png",
    "Curtains.png",
    "Refrigerator.png",
    "Water Heater.png",
    "Microwave Oven.png"
)
```

I send data as,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {
    MZFormSheetPresentationViewControllerSegue *presentationSegue = (id)segue;
    presentationSegue.formSheetPresentationController.presentationController.shouldApplyBackgroundBlurEffect = YES;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (id)presentationSegue.formSheetPresentationController.contentViewController;
    AmennitiesTableTableViewController *presentedViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
//        presentedViewController.textFieldBecomeFirstResponder = YES;

    presentedViewController.passingString = facilities;

}
```

and receive data in table view controller,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close)];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.passingString);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I tried showing the mutable array as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"facilitiesCell";
    AmenitiesTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.facilitylbl.text = [self.passingString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

But I am not understanding what exactly i am missing to Populate data on the tableview.

Comment: Missing info: Are `self.tableView`'s `delegate` and `datasource` set? Did you return in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` `self.passingString.count`?

Comment: @S.Sallay Add error code here from console log.

Comment: It is , [UITableViewCell facilitylbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89c9c44400 2017-02-08 09:44:48.567 krib[914:49152] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell facilitylbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89c9c44400' . Reminder, I use NSMutable array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to set tableview delegate & datasource.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close)];
    [self.myTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.myTable setDataSource:self];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.passingString);
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.passingString.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"facilitiesCell";
   AmenitiesTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(self.passingString.count > 0){
        cell.facilitylbl.text = [self.passingString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }

// Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Still I get the error as ,[UITableViewCell facilitylbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89c9c44400
2017-02-08 09:44:48.567 krib[914:49152] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell facilitylbl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89c9c44400'

Comment: bro can you check you have given your `AmenitiesTableCell` Go to identity inspector make sure you have give your custom class. And once again you can remove `facilitylbl' outlet and add once again.